# What If All Users Downloaded ClickOnce App Pointing to an Invalid Update Path?

Tags: .net, wpf, deployment, configuration, clickonce

I have a test environment with an update path of a ClickOnce App pointing to *"\\TestPC\TestFolder"*.
When I need to deploy a release to the client, then I change this path to "\\RealPC\RealFolder".

I am wondering what can I do if I mistake the release, and deploy to the client an app with a wrong path (my test environment path), which it does not even exists at the client environment and everyone already downloaded the new version.

One solution that I thought is to ask the client to name one computer as "TestPC" and create a folder "TestFolder" on it, so I can deploy a new version on it, but this time, pointing to "\\RealPC\RealFolder". This way, everyone will initially download the version from the test folder (which was the mistake), but then, they will update from the real folder.

Altought, this solution may be a little creepy to the client. What else can I do to fix it in a simpler way?

Comment: Send an apologetic email to your customers, explain what went wrong and how to can see it being wrong by themselves.  And give them a good download location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible for you, host the click once via IIS in both pcs & keep the same name.
Also, if you are using a database. you can add an entry of latest version in it & check this on load.

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand the "database" process that you said.

Comment: In your app.config, you maintain a Config key Eg "Version=1.6.1.0" 
& in a database table also you keep this value. 
While loading your exe. you can check this value of your app to match with the value present in the database.
While deploying, just update these 2 versions.
You can extend this solution also via keeping options such as min reqd version, test version etc.
(The same thing which click once gives.)

Comment: On every deployment, you will have to update the version in both the database table as well as app.config. 
Even if some one has old copy of your exe (or you have mis-deployed at some different site), 
it will not work since the version in that exe will not match the version in your database.
You can inform the user via a simple message box that he is using wrong version of exe when it loads.
& thus you always ensure that user is using the latest exe meant for him.

Comment: On a different note, 
If you make the same mistake twice (i.e. the update wrong entry in database table as well as app.config), then you seriously need a break.

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant's comment is a great way to deal with this kind of errors, so you should create a new installer, distribute a link for that in an apologizing email, in which you can explain the problem to your customers.

Also, you can create a standalone patch, which can modify the update path of your application on your customers machines, for details, see this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16z3sw0x.aspx), but this also requires you to reach out to all customers, you still have to explain why this path is needed, so I guess I would stick with the first option.

Comment: I just can't believe that ClickOnce doesn't provide a better solution. This problem is a risky one. Imagine if Skype sent an email to everyone asking for apologize and requesting to download a patch or a new application again? I think if I have time in a project to create my own update library, I would prefer to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup the working network share `\\TestPC\TestFolder` within your customers network. It is not possible to do it without this step. You will have to handle it with your customer's IT somehow.

It should not be very difficult - they can add alias `TestPC` to an existing server in DNS and then share one folder.

Then this problem could be solved the same way as changing the URL of an existing working ClickOnce deployment from one server to another.

There is a little trick described in [this video](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/how-to-move-a-clickonce-deployment/).

The main point of this trick is:

- you have installed e.g. version 1.1.0.0 installed from `\\TestPC\TestFolder`
- that you publish a new update to a new location `\\RealPC\RealFolder` with higher version e.g. 1.3.0.0
- that you publish a transition update to the old location `\\TestPC\TestFolder` with version between the new and the old version, e.g. 1.2.0.0. This transiton update must have the Update location set to `\\RealPC\RealFolder`

[image]

You can make the 1.2.0.0 update on `\\TestPC\TestFolder` required to force upgrade.
I usually try to track the clients version in a central database to be sure that all the clients have the desired version.